# How to save a pdf file to file system (ios/android) with react native which can be accessible outside the app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am receiving the pdf as base64 encoded string from an api and I want to convert this base64 string to pdf and save it in file system of the device.
And this file should be accessible outside the app.

Environment : React Native, Expo

What it the best library that I can use.

Looked at lots of resources online, but confused whether they save in local app storage or outside the app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Expo, probably Expo FileSystem. Because it's an expo package, it works really well in testing and will be easy to implement to your project. [Here are the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/).

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that its easy to work with byte stream instead a base64 string.

And as Finley suggested above, using Expo libraries, **Expo File-System, Expo Media-Library, Expo-Sharing** can be used together to save the image to device storage which can be accessed from outside app.

In case of IOS, use Expo-Sharing to open sharing options and from there we can save a file to file system.